# SharePoint 2010 Word automation service and Event Receiver

Tags: c#, ms-word, sharepoint-2010, pdf-generation, eventreceiver

I am working on SharePoint 2010 event receiver. I run this event receiver on specific list and on certain conditions I create copy of word document in a library and edit its properties with dynamic values and then use word automation service to convert this document to PDF in same library.

My word document is created correctly with required document properties inserted inside the word document. The code is executed correctly however the document is not converted to PDF.

Below is the conversion code:

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://MySharePoint Site"))
            {

                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(spSite.WebApplication.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup, SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier.Default);

                var wordAutomationProxy = (WordServiceApplicationProxy)serviceContext.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(WordServiceApplicationProxy));

                //Defines a collection of settings for all conversions within a single conversion job.
                ConversionJobSettings jobSettings = new ConversionJobSettings();
                jobSettings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
                //Represents a collection of file conversions (of single files or entire libraries) that share a common set of conversion properties and are logically tracked as a single unit.
                ConversionJob pdfConversion = new ConversionJob(wordAutomationProxy, jobSettings);
              // Set the credentials to use when running the conversion job.
                pdfConversion.UserToken = spSite.UserToken;                    
                pdfConversion.AddFile(DocFilePath, PDFFilePath);
                pdfConversion.Start();

}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the word automation service and that resolved my issue. No code changes.